# Javascript - Using variable as object key to get object value

Tags: javascript

In the following code, I would like to retrieve person1 and person4 (the first person in the array) in a loop. This works when explicitly identifying the property. But when using a variable 'myField' to represent the property, it returns undefined... What would be the syntax to get the value?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8vr06Ltk/3/

```js
    var companies = [
      { 
        "description":"company1", 
        "people": [{"name":"person1"},{"name":"person2"},{"name":"person3"}],
        "date":"2020-01-01"
      },
      { 
        "description":"company2", 
        "people": [{"name":"person4"},{"name":"person5"},{"name":"person6"}],
        "date":"2020-01-01"
      } 
    ]


var myField = "people[0].name";

for (var key in companies) {
  console.log(companies[key].people[0].name); /* correct: returns person1 and person4 */
  console.log(companies[key].myField); /* incorrect: undefined */
  console.log(companies[key][myField]); /* incorrect: undefined */
}
```

Comment: because it is looking for `{ "people[0].name" : "foo" }`.

Comment: You could use a template string to pass in your variable 
```var myField = "name";
for (var key in companies) {
  console.log(companies[key].people[0][`${myField}`]); /* correct: returns person1 and person4 */
}```

Comment: @portatlas Due to some other constraints, I need to have the entire structure of myField as a variable.

Comment: Could you use something like jsonata https://try.jsonata.org/? you could pass in your variable as a query to get back the results you are looking for.